# How get next (previous) element in std::list without incrementing (decrementing) iterator?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Say I have an `std::list<int> lst` and some `std::list<int>::iterator it` for iterating through the list. And depended to value of the `it` I want to use `it + 1` or `it - 1` in my code. Is there some good way to do that like `next()`, `prev()` (I couldn't find such things in stl documentation)? Or should I copy the `it` each time and increment(decrement) the copy?

Comment: When you do `it++`, it translates as `it = it + 1`, meaning technically the iterator object could just as well be a new object everytime.  Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Copying and incrementing/decrementing the copy is the only way it can be done. You can write wrapper functions to hide it (and as mentioned in answers, C++11 has `std::prev`/`std::next` which do just that. But they are wrappers around this "copy and increment" operation

Comment: Thanks @jalf. Your Answer is the only full answer.

Comment: @elusive I have putted `"it + 1"` and `"it - 1"` to the quotes because they are not valid operations of the bidirectional iterator. Do you care if I add them back?

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan: you can put the quotes back if you like. I don't think they're necessary though (because it's already clear that this is what you *want* to do, but it can't be done). And thanks, I'll post it as an answer then :)

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan: I do not think the quotes are necessary. The problem is that they _may_ be interpreted as strings, which is clearly not what you intended. Thats why I removed them. ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Copying and incrementing/decrementing the copy is the only way it can be done.

You can write wrapper functions to hide it (and as mentioned in answers, C++11 has std::prev/std::next which do just that (and Boost defines similar functions). But they are wrappers around this "copy and increment" operation, so you don't have to worry that you're doing it "wrong".

Answer (score 61):

Yes, since C++11 there are the two methods you are looking for called `std::prev` and `std::next`. You can find them in the iterator library.

Example from cppreference.com

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
 
int main() 
{
    std::list<int> v{ 3, 1, 4 };
 
    auto it = v.begin();
 
    auto nx = std::next(it, 2);
 
    std::cout << *it << ' ' << *nx << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3 4
```

Comment: And of course, if you don't have C++11, they're very easy to implement.  (I think most of us had them in our toolkits well before they were even proposed for C++11.)

Comment: If you don't have C++11, just use `std::advance()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

A simple precanned solution are `prior` and `next` from [`Boost.utility`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/utility.htm). They take advantage of `operator--` and `operator++` but don't require you to create a temporary.

Comment: Of course it should be mentionned that 1. They create the temporary on their own and 2. You'd better be aware of boundary conditions.