# How to use std::list as the implementation of an interface for a list that exposes the nodes?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdlist

I have the interface of a doubly-linked list that exposes its edges. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class Listnode
{
public:
    Listnode *prev;
    Listnode *next;
    T val;
};

template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
    Listnode *head;
    Listnode *tail;
    // insert, remove, etc.
};
```

Assume that external old code uses this interface.

I took the implementation of `std::list::sort` and imitated it in `List`. However, it would be nicer to use it, if possible, instead of copying.

**Question:** Is it possible to use `std::list` somehow to get the implementation of `List::sort`? In particular, use `std::list::sort` to modify the `prev`-`next` pointers of the `ListNode`'s of the `List` such that the `List` ends up sorted. Well, without essentially duplicating the list inside an `std::list`.

**My answer:** It seems to me that it won't be possible since `std::list`, as far as I can see [in the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), doesn't expose (see also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137214/how-get-next-previous-element-in-stdlist-without-incrementing-decrementing)) the edges between nodes, except traversing them through its iterator, while its implementation of `std::list::sort` seems to modify directly the edges, or at least it works with the iterators until a call to a method (`_M_transfer`), like in [the GNU implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/a00925_source.html).

But I am a beginner. I could be easily be missing something.

Comment: It's a bad idea to sort lists. It's much better to sort a vector, or if you *must* have a list, to sort a vector of pointers to list elements.

Comment: What advantage would your code have over using a `std::list` with its iterator? `ListNode` is very similar in functionality to an iterator (allows to move to previous/next node and get the value). **Don't reinvent the wheel**.

Comment: @Phil1970 Read the sentence right after the code block.

Comment: Then, does it have to be exactly like that with public members? If you can make minor changes to the interface, in the end, it might be much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make `std::list` conform to what you're trying to do. The closest you could do is have the `T` in your `Listnode` type be a `std::list<ActualT>::iterator` to the element in the `std::list`. But if this interface is being used by existing code that has its own expectations for what `T` is, that's not really an option.